# Does the differential operator and the Real operator commute?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have the differential operator for $x$, to the arbitrary $n^{th}$ order denoted by:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$$

I have the Real operator denoted by:

$$Re\{u + iv\} = u\, ,$$

where $u$ and $v$ are real functions.

Is it always true that:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[Re\left\{f(x)\right\}\right] = Re\left\{\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[f(x)\right]\right\}\,,$$
where $f(x)$ is an imaginary function.

Comment: If you mean $f(x) = g(x)+ih(x)$ where $g,h$ are real-valued, then $f'(x)=g'(x)+ih'(x),$  so the answer is yes.

Comment: Are there cases where $f(x)$ cannot be decomposed into $g(x)$ and $h(x)$?

Comment: Not if I understand your question correctly.  I was unsure about the statement "$f(x)$ is an imaginary function."  This would usually be stated as "$f(x)$ is a complex-valued function of a real variable."   If this is what you meant, then certainly $f(x) = g(x)+ih(x)$